# Settings > Basic > Site URL - Exact Match

Tags: facebook-php-sdk

I am getting "An error occurred with [App Name]. Please try again later." when testing the PHP SDK. From what I've read it is most likely because my App > Settings > Basic > Site URL does not match the redirect_uri.

My Site URL is the domain root and my redirect_uri is the domain root with two get parameters. Does the redirect_uri have to match the Site URL exactly?

Also, is there a way to track error numbers so that I can easily tell what error is taking place? Facebook does not seem to show errors to the users and I am wondering where they report api errors so that they can be easily debugged.

Answer (score 0):

The Site URL should be the prefix of the redirect_uri. For example, if you site URL is http://www.example.com redirect_uri can be http://www.example.com/path/to/page. You can get the error number from the response JSON, although the numbers are admittedly a bit inconsistent. We are working on improving and clarifying that, and I'll post an update when I have more info.